# Wine installation error winehq-stable : Dependent: wine-stable (= 9.0.0.0.0~jammy-1)

Tags: 22.04, wine

Error output when installing Wine:

```
nessie27@nessie27-MS-7A38:~$ sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building a dependency tree... Done
Reading status information... Done         
Some packages cannot be installed. Perhaps what you're asking for
is not feasible, or you may be using an unstable version of the distribution where
the packages you requested have not yet been created or have been removed from Incoming.
The following information may help you:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Dependencies: wine-stable (= 9.0.0.0.0~jammy-1)
E: Unable to fix errors: you have broken packages committed.
```

`sudo dpkg -l | grep '^.[^i]'` command output:

```
rc  fuse                                           2.9.9-5ubuntu3                                         amd64        Filesystem in Userspace
rc  linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic                   6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1                                    amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-modules-6.2.0-26-generic                 6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1                                    amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-26-generic           6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1                                    amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-535-6.2.0-26-generic      6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1+2                                  amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.2.0-26
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-535-6.2.0-39-generic      6.2.0-39.40~22.04.1+1                                  amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.2.0-39
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-535-6.2.0-26-generic      6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1+2                                  amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.2.0-26 (objects)
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-535-6.2.0-39-generic      6.2.0-39.40~22.04.1+1                                  amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.2.0-39 (objects)
rc  ntfs-3g                                        1:2021.8.22-3ubuntu1.2                                 amd64        read/write NTFS driver for FUSE
rc  steam-launcher                                 1:1.0.0.78                                             all          Launcher for the Steam software distribution service
rc  virtualbox                                     6.1.48-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.22.04.1                          amd64        x86 virtualization solution - base binaries
rc  xdg-desktop-portal                             1.14.4-1ubuntu2~22.04.1                                amd64        desktop integration portal for Flatpak and Snap
```

Output of `dpkg --list | grep --color=auto linux-image`:

```
rc  linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic                   6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1                                    amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-6.2.0-39-generic                   6.2.0-39.40~22.04.1                                    amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-6.5.0-14-generic                   6.5.0-14.14~22.04.1                                    amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-6.5.0-15-generic                   6.5.0-15.15~22.04.1                                    amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04                  6.5.0.15.15~22.04.8                                    amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

Output of `uname -r`:

```
6.5.0-15-generic
```

Comment: Please update your question with output of `sudo dpkg -l | grep '^.[^i]'` . You have broken packages, which needs to be fixed before you can install any package.

Comment: Also provide information about the current kernel in use with `uname -r` .

Comment: Is that all the output of `dpkg -l | grep '^.[^i]'` ?

Comment: Yes, there's nothing else

Comment: @VanessaFoht Please [edit] your question with the output of `grep -i 'wine' -r /etc/apt; ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d; apt-mark showhold; apt-cache policy winehq-stable wine-stable`

Comment: Are the broken packages preventing you from installing any new packages to your system, using `apt` or `synaptic`, etc.? Or is it just `wine`?

Comment: @rusty I assume not because according to https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta-hwe-6.5 , 6.5.0.15.15~22.04.8 was released a week ago. With the computer upgraded successful last week, and wine 9.0.0.0~jammy-1 released before that, I find that unlikely, but I edited my answer with an apt upgrade

Comment: @VanessaFoht can you install `sudo apt install synaptic` , a GUI package manager for .deb packages?

Comment: @VanessaFoht If you are not comfortable with the command line, you can try **Alternative 02** in my answer. See if that works. If `apt` fails to install any app, you need to try the **Alternative 01**.

Comment: For some just a single command can fix it: `sudo apt-get --fix-broken install`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE: (solution)**

I had the exact same issue on three different systems, all running Ubuntu 22.04.03, and none of the suggestions here helped. What I did find to work however, is aptitude.

```
sudo apt install aptitude
```

```
sudo aptitude install winehq-stable
```

select no to first suggestion to "do nothing", accept 2nd suggestions.

```
kenneth@gallifrey:~$ sudo aptitude install winehq-stable
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  winehq-stable{b}
0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1788 B of archives. After unpacking 74.8 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 9.0.0.0~jammy-1) but it is not installable
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     winehq-stable [Not Installed]



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Install the following packages:
1)      ipp-usb [0.9.20-1ubuntu0.22.04.1 (jammy-security, jammy-updates)]
2)      libavahi-client3:i386 [0.8-5ubuntu5.2 (jammy-security, jammy-updates)]
3)      libavahi-common-data:i386 [0.8-5ubuntu5.2 (jammy-security, jammy-updates)]
4)      libavahi-common3:i386 [0.8-5ubuntu5.2 (jammy-security, jammy-updates)]
5)      libbrotli1:i386 [1.0.9-2build6 (jammy)]
6)      libbz2-1.0:i386 [1.0.8-5build1 (jammy)]
7)      libcairo2:i386 [1.16.0-5ubuntu2 (jammy)]
8)      libcapi20-3:i386 [1:3.27-3 (jammy)]
9)      libcups2:i386 [2.4.1op1-1ubuntu4.7 (jammy-security, jammy-updates)]
10)     libcurl3-gnutls:i386 [7.81.0-1 (jammy)]
11)     libcurl4:i386 [7.81.0-1ubuntu1.15 (jammy-security, jammy-updates)]
12)     libdeflate0:i386 [1.10-2 (jammy)]
13)     libdw1:i386 [0.186-1build1 (jammy)]
14)     libexif12:i386 [0.6.24-1build1 (jammy)]
15)     libfontconfig1:i386 [2.13.1-4.2ubuntu5 (jammy)]
16)     libfreetype6:i386 [2.11.1+dfsg-1ubuntu0.2 (jammy-security, jammy-updates)]
17)     libgd3:i386 [2.3.0-2ubuntu2 (jammy)]
18)     libgdbm-compat4:i386 [1.23-1 (jammy)]
19)     libgdbm6:i386 [1.23-1 (jammy)]
20)     libglib2.0-0:i386 [2.72.4-0ubuntu2.2 (jammy-security, jammy-updates)]
21)     libgmp10:i386 [2:6.2.1+dfsg-3ubuntu1 (jammy)]
22)     libgnutls30:i386 [3.7.3-4ubuntu1.4 (jammy-security, jammy-updates)]
23)     libgphoto2-6:i386 [2.5.27-1build2 (jammy)]
24)     libgphoto2-l10n [2.5.27-1build2 (jammy)]
25)     libgphoto2-port12:i386 [2.5.27-1build2 (jammy)]
26)     libgpm2:i386 [1.20.7-10build1 (jammy)]
27)     libgsm1:i386 [1.0.19-1 (jammy)]
28)     libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 [1.20.1-1ubuntu0.1 (jammy-security, jammy-updates)]
29)     libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 [1.20.3-0ubuntu1 (jammy-updates)]
30)     libhogweed6:i386 [3.7.3-1build2 (jammy)]
31)     libieee1284-3:i386 [0.2.11-14build2 (jammy)]
32)     libjbig0:i386 [2.1-3.1ubuntu0.22.04.1 (jammy-security, jammy-updates)]
33)     libjpeg-turbo8:i386 [2.1.2-0ubuntu1 (jammy)]
34)     libjpeg8:i386 [8c-2ubuntu10 (jammy)]
35)     liblcms2-2:i386 [2.12~rc1-2build2 (jammy)]
36)     libldap-2.5-0:i386 [2.5.16+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 (jammy-security, jammy-updates)]
37)     libltdl7:i386 [2.4.6-15build2 (jammy)]
38)     libmount1:i386 [2.37.2-4ubuntu3 (jammy)]
39)     libncurses6:i386 [6.3-2ubuntu0.1 (jammy-security, jammy-updates)]
40)     libnettle8:i386 [3.7.3-1build2 (jammy)]
41)     libnghttp2-14:i386 [1.43.0-1ubuntu0.1 (jammy-security, jammy-updates)]
42)     libnspr4:i386 [2:4.32-3build1 (jammy)]
43)     libnss3:i386 [2:3.68.2-0ubuntu1.2 (jammy-security, jammy-updates)]
44)     libodbc2:i386 [2.3.9-5 (jammy)]
45)     libopenjp2-7:i386 [2.4.0-6 (jammy)]
46)     liborc-0.4-0:i386 [1:0.4.32-2 (jammy)]
47)     libosmesa6:i386 [23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1 (jammy-updates)]
48)     libp11-kit0:i386 [0.24.0-6build1 (jammy)]
49)     libpcap0.8:i386 [1.10.1-4build1 (jammy)]
50)     libpci3:i386 [1:3.7.0-6 (jammy)]
51)     libpcre2-8-0:i386 [10.39-3build1 (jammy)]
52)     libpcre3:i386 [2:8.39-13ubuntu0.22.04.1 (jammy-security, jammy-updates)]
53)     libperl5.34:i386 [5.34.0-3ubuntu1.3 (jammy-security, jammy-updates)]
54)     libpixman-1-0:i386 [0.40.0-1ubuntu0.22.04.1 (jammy-security, jammy-updates)]
55)     libpng16-16:i386 [1.6.37-3build5 (jammy)]
56)     libpoppler-glib8:i386 [22.02.0-2ubuntu0.3 (jammy-security, jammy-updates)]
57)     libpoppler118:i386 [22.02.0-2ubuntu0.3 (jammy-security, jammy-updates)]
58)     libpsl5:i386 [0.21.0-1.2build2 (jammy)]
59)     librtmp1:i386 [2.4+20151223.gitfa8646d.1-2build4 (jammy)]
60)     libsane-common [1.1.1-5 (jammy)]
61)     libsane1:i386 [1.1.1-5 (jammy)]
62)     libsasl2-2:i386 [2.1.27+dfsg2-3ubuntu1.2 (jammy-updates)]
63)     libsasl2-modules:i386 [2.1.27+dfsg2-3ubuntu1.2 (jammy-updates)]
64)     libsasl2-modules-db:i386 [2.1.27+dfsg2-3ubuntu1.2 (jammy-updates)]
65)     libselinux1:i386 [3.3-1build2 (jammy)]
66)     libsnmp-base [5.9.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2.6 (jammy-updates)]
67)     libsnmp40:i386 [5.9.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2.6 (jammy-updates)]
68)     libsqlite3-0:i386 [3.37.2-2ubuntu0.3 (jammy-security, jammy-updates)]
69)     libssh-4:i386 [0.9.6-2ubuntu0.22.04.3 (jammy-security, jammy-updates)]
70)     libtasn1-6:i386 [4.18.0-4build1 (jammy)]
71)     libtiff5:i386 [4.3.0-6ubuntu0.7 (jammy-security, jammy-updates)]
72)     libunwind8:i386 [1.3.2-2build2.1 (jammy-updates)]
73)     libusb-1.0-0:i386 [2:1.0.25-1ubuntu2 (jammy-updates)]
74)     libv4l-0:i386 [1.22.1-2build1 (jammy)]
75)     libv4lconvert0:i386 [1.22.1-2build1 (jammy)]
76)     libwebp7:i386 [1.2.2-2ubuntu0.22.04.2 (jammy-security, jammy-updates)]
77)     libwrap0:i386 [7.6.q-31build2 (jammy)]
78)     libxcb-render0:i386 [1.14-3ubuntu3 (jammy)]
79)     libxcomposite1:i386 [1:0.4.5-1build2 (jammy)]
80)     libxkbregistry0:i386 [1.4.0-1 (jammy)]
81)     libxpm4:i386 [1:3.5.12-1ubuntu0.22.04.2 (jammy-security, jammy-updates)]
82)     libxslt1.1:i386 [1.1.34-4ubuntu0.22.04.1 (jammy-security, jammy-updates)]
83)     ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 [2.2.14-3 (jammy)]
84)     sane-utils:i386 [1.1.1-5 (jammy)]
85)     wine-stable:i386 [9.0.0.0~jammy-1 (jammy)]
86)     wine-stable-i386:i386 [9.0.0.0~jammy-1 (jammy)]

      Downgrade the following packages:
87)     libcurl3-gnutls [7.81.0-1ubuntu1.15 (jammy-security, jammy-updates, now) -> 7.81.0-1 (jammy)]
88)     libpcre2-8-0 [10.40-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (now) -> 10.39-3build1 (jammy)]

      Leave the following dependencies unresolved:
89)     libsane1:i386 recommends sane-airscan:i386
90)     libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 recommends gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386
91)     wine-stable-i386:i386 recommends libglu1-mesa:i386 | libglu1:i386



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] Y
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  libcurl3-gnutls libpcre2-8-0
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ipp-usb{a} libavahi-client3:i386{a} libavahi-common-data:i386{a} libavahi-common3:i386{a} libbrotli1:i386{a} libbz2-1.0:i386{a} libcairo2:i386{a} libcapi20-3:i386{a} libcups2:i386{a}
  libcurl3-gnutls:i386{a} libcurl4:i386{a} libdeflate0:i386{a} libdw1:i386{a} libexif12:i386{a} libfontconfig1:i386{a} libfreetype6:i386{a} libgd3:i386{a} libgdbm-compat4:i386{a}
  libgdbm6:i386{a} libglib2.0-0:i386{a} libgmp10:i386{a} libgnutls30:i386{a} libgphoto2-6:i386{a} libgphoto2-l10n{a} libgphoto2-port12:i386{a} libgpm2:i386{a} libgsm1:i386{a}
  libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386{a} libgstreamer1.0-0:i386{a} libhogweed6:i386{a} libieee1284-3:i386{a} libjbig0:i386{a} libjpeg-turbo8:i386{a} libjpeg8:i386{a} liblcms2-2:i386{a}
  libldap-2.5-0:i386{a} libltdl7:i386{a} libmount1:i386{a} libncurses6:i386{a} libnettle8:i386{a} libnghttp2-14:i386{a} libnspr4:i386{a} libnss3:i386{a} libodbc2:i386{a} libopenjp2-7:i386{a}
  liborc-0.4-0:i386{a} libosmesa6:i386{a} libp11-kit0:i386{a} libpcap0.8:i386{a} libpci3:i386{a} libpcre2-8-0:i386{a} libpcre3:i386{a} libperl5.34:i386{a} libpixman-1-0:i386{a}
  libpng16-16:i386{a} libpoppler-glib8:i386{a} libpoppler118:i386{a} libpsl5:i386{a} librtmp1:i386{a} libsane-common{a} libsane1:i386{a} libsasl2-2:i386{a} libsasl2-modules:i386{a}
  libsasl2-modules-db:i386{a} libselinux1:i386{a} libsnmp-base{a} libsnmp40:i386{a} libsqlite3-0:i386{a} libssh-4:i386{a} libtasn1-6:i386{a} libtiff5:i386{a} libunwind8:i386{a}
  libusb-1.0-0:i386{a} libv4l-0:i386{a} libv4lconvert0:i386{a} libwebp7:i386{a} libwrap0:i386{a} libxcb-render0:i386{a} libxcomposite1:i386{a} libxkbregistry0:i386{a} libxpm4:i386{a}
  libxslt1.1:i386{a} ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386{a} sane-utils:i386{a} wine-stable:i386{a} wine-stable-i386:i386{a} winehq-stable
The following packages are RECOMMENDED but will NOT be installed:
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386
0 packages upgraded, 87 newly installed, 2 downgraded, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 136 MB of archives. After unpacking 752 MB will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] Y
Get: 1 http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libsane-common all 1.1.1-5 [915 kB]
Get: 2 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy/main i386 wine-stable-i386 i386 9.0.0.0~jammy-1 [101 MB]
<SNIPPED...>
Get: 89 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 winehq-stable amd64 9.0.0.0~jammy-1 [1788 B]
Fetched 136 MB in 4s (37.0 MB/s)
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package libsane-common.
(Reading database ... 174184 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-libsane-common_1.1.1-5_all.deb ...
Unpacking libsane-common (1.1.1-5) ...
<SNIPPED...>
Scanning processes...
Scanning candidates...
Scanning processor microcode...
Scanning linux images...

Running kernel seems to be up-to-date.

The processor microcode seems to be up-to-date.

No containers need to be restarted.

No user sessions are running outdated binaries.

No VM guests are running outdated hypervisor (qemu) binaries on this host.

Current status: 4 (+4) upgradable.

kenneth@gallifrey:~$ wine --version
wine-9.0
kenneth@gallifrey:~$
```

Comment: Wow! Aptitude is amazing.

Comment: I can't tell if you're being sarcastic or not @OrganicMarble, but in this case, it sure was :)

Comment: No, not sarcastic. aptitude has saved me many times. But this seems like a whole new level of awesome.

Comment: Good, hopefully it will solve OP Vanessas' issue as well. I believe it will, since I had the exact same error message.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Aptitude didn't list proposals for correction. Returned                                                                            "No solution found within the allotted time." after several restarts.

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by an incompatible previous installation of wine. Reinstall your desired version:

1. `apt-mark showhold`. If this returns any output, do `sudo apt-mark unhold <name>`
2. Disable every PPA except the `winehq-jammy.sources` one by moving their files away from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`
3. `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`, in case you forgot to do so while following [WineHQ's instructions](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu)
4. `sudo apt update`
5. `sudo apt-get purge 'wine*' 'wine*:i386'` This line will do the trick. Make sure to read everything below the "The following packages will be REMOVED" line and cancel if it wants to remove something you want.
6. `sudo apt autopurge`. If it wants to remove something you want, cancel, and do `sudo apt install <name>`, then try again
7. `sudo apt upgrade`
8. `sudo apt full-upgrade`
9. `sudo apt install wine-stable:i386`
10. `sudo apt install wine-stable`
11. `sudo apt install winehq-stable`
12. `sudo apt install winehq-stable --install-recommends`

Also ensure that you did not pin any repositories in `/etc/apt/preferences.d`

[Alternatively](https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=38435), try:

1. `sudo apt install --install-recommends wine-stable-i386:i386`
2. `sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable`

Comment: what you mean by apt problems and how to fix them?

Comment: apt problems just means when your apt commands are giving you errors. To fix them, does following my steps work? If not, what is the error?

Comment: Followed all the instructions, didn't help(

Comment: After following all the instructions, the error remains

Comment: @VanessaFoht I added an alternative, as well as added to the original. If that doesn't work, you could try replying to the forum thread at https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=38435 or follow rusty's answer or rusty's comment

Answer (score 1):

***Alternative 01:***

The output of `sudo dpkg -l | grep '^.[^i]'` shows you can remove the following packages as done with `dpkg --remove ...` (these were listed `rc`). (There is a description at: [How to interpret the status of dpkg (–list)](https://linuxprograms.wordpress.com/2010/05/11/status-dpkg-list/))

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-all fuse ntfs-3g steam-launcher virtualbox xdg-desktop-portal linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic linux-modules-6.2.0-26-generic linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-26-generic linux-modules-nvidia-535-6.2.0-26-generic linux-modules-nvidia-535-6.2.0-39-generic linux-objects-nvidia-535-6.2.0-26-generic linux-objects-nvidia-535-6.2.0-39-generic
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get --fix-broken install
```

Now verify that you have the following packages:

```
apt-cache policy fuse ntfs-3g steam-launcher virtualbox xdg-desktop-portal
```

If, you don't have them, you can install with:

```
sudo apt install fuse ntfs-3g steam-launcher virtualbox xdg-desktop-portal
```

Now you should also be able to install any other programs. e.g. wine with:

```
sudo apt install wine
```

***Alternative 02:***

Install `synaptic` package manager with:

```
sudo apt install synaptic
```

Launch *Synaptic Package Manager* and go to **Custom Filters -> Broken**, a list of broken packages will be listed. You need to select them in the checkbox and mark them for removal. And apply the changes. The GUI application will handle the broken packages for you.

[image: synaptic]