# Error installing Wine on Ubuntu 22.04.4

Tags: apt, 22.04, wine, dependencies

I've followed thoroughly [all steps](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu) of Wine installation under Ubuntu 22.04.4 (fresh install), but on step

`sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable`

I receive an error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 9.0.0.0~jammy-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried first solution to this problem from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1502078/wine-installation-error-winehq-stable-dependent-wine-stable-9-0-0-0-0jamm) but on step `sudo apt install wine-stable:i386` I get the same error with comments. And it looks like all the packages apt complains about are already installed and have the latest version, as shown on the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Your output clearly shows at least one non-Ubuntu package with a not-quite-the-same version.

Comment: I managed to install it on ubuntu 22.04.3 before and it worked.

Comment: @Apogentus could you add output of `uname -a` also `echo q | aptitude -s install winehq-stable` and `apt-cache policy winehq-stable` to the question. BTW, try best to include terminal output as text instead of screenshot, it is hard to index and trace info from pictures.

Comment: Did you remove older wine installs before you try to install this one? Did you add 32-bit arch? I can install it without any problems.

Comment: Yes, I installed 32-bit arch. Tried to purge wine and reinstall - same problem. Ended up removing Ubuntu 22.04.4 and installing Ubuntu 23.10. Wine-stable installed on 23.10 without any problems.